# Selecting a element by it's css selector in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, puppeteer

I'm trying to select an image element using its style selector. I wrote the line of code in Python but I'm having problems translating it to JavaScript. Here's my attempt so far. Please note the python code works. It's the js I'm having problems with.

```
if driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[style='object-fit: cover;']") is not None:
        download_url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[style='object-fit: cover;']").get_attribute('src')
```

And here is my js attempt.

```
let imageArr = []

for(let post of posts) {
    await page.goto(post)
    await page.waitForTimeout(6000)

    if (await page.type("img[style='object-fit: cover;']") !== null) {

        const image = await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.querySelectorAll("img[style='object-fit: cover;']").forEach(img => {
                let imageUrl = img.getAttribute('src');
                imageArr.push(imageUrl)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: For this `querySelectorAll("img[style='object-fit: cover;']")` to match elements, those image elements have to have that style _(and only that style)_ inline with the exact spacing and semi-colon. Is that the case?

Comment: @Kinglish yes. That's right

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `*` CSS attribute selector, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> [attr*=value] - Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

So for your Javascript code, I believe this will work:

```js
let imageArr = []

for(let post of posts) {
    await page.goto(post)
    await page.waitForTimeout(6000)

    if (await page.type("img[style*='object-fit: cover;']") !== null) {

        const image = await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.querySelectorAll("img[style*='object-fit: cover;']").forEach(img => {
                let imageUrl = img.getAttribute('src');
                imageArr.push(imageUrl)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

This will select all `img` elements that have at least one occurrence of `object-fit: cover;` within the string.

Comment: The Python code is correct. I'm translating this to javascript. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: I misread the question, my bad. I changed the answer to add the Javascript code instead.

Comment: Sorry, @Milo Fultz. I get the same errors I'm still getting. I think your code is similar to mine. Which has problems.

Comment: If you share the page you're scraping and the desired output, it'd be a lot easier to validate any proposed solutions. Otherwise, it's pretty much flying blind. `await page.waitForTimeout(6000)` is generally a mistake. Best to `waitForFunction` or `waitForSelector`.